# Running a method when one is done in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a class called **DownloadData** it's passed from a fragment. It downloads all the JSON data I need and stores them to **SQLite DB**, it's working fine. But, when I pass the function to populate on my ListView, my app crashes. I added it to the **onViewCreated** method, it throws **NullPointerException** meaning the Database is empty, but when I add it to the end of the method in the class that helps download my data. **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment.**  My code is below:

```
Public class DataRetrieval{
handleJson();
public void handleResponse {
//My work goes here.....
getResults();
}
}


    public class PendingFragment extends ListFragment{

    Context activityContext;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    //Context context;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pending_frag, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        return android;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //getResults();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
        OrderDataRetrieval ord = new OrderDataRetrieval(getActivity());
        SharedPreferences pref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
        String getToken = pref.getString("key1", "no data");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://" + getActivity().getString(R.string.AUTORITY_ORDER) + "/orders");
        Uri itemUri = Uri.parse("content://" + getActivity().getString(R.string.AUTORITY_ORDER) + "/item");
        Uri issuesUri = Uri.parse("content://" + getActivity().getString(R.string.AUTORITY_ORDER) + "/issue");
        ord.getData(getToken, uri, itemUri, issuesUri);
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

    public void getResults(){
        This is the line the error points to --> Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://" + getString(R.string.AUTORITY_ORDER) + "/orders");
        String dbUri = uri.toString();
        ContentProvider cp = null;
        final Cursor cursor = cp.query(uri, null, null, null, "_id");
        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(cursor.toString());
            JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(cursor.toString());
            Log.d("TAG JSONOBJ", jObj.toString());
            Log.d("TAG JSONArr", jArr.toString());
            parseJsonFeed(jObj);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject jObj){


    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         activityContext = activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDetach();
        try {
            Field child1 = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("PENDING");
            child1.setAccessible(true);
            child1.set(this, null);

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //getResults();
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Below is my Logcat

```
09-14 11:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(25124): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment PendingFragment{41e34b00} not attached to Activity
09-14 11:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(25124):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:603)
09-14 11:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(25124):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:625)
09-14 11:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(25124):    at com.deliveryscience.pod.fragments.PendingFragment.getResults(PendingFragment.java:75)
09-14 11:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(25124):    at com.deliveryscience.pod.handlers.OrderDataRetrieval.handleResponse(OrderDataRetrieval.java:117)
09-14 11:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(25124):    at com.deliveryscience.pod.handlers.OrderDataRetrieval$1.onResponse(OrderDataRetrieval.java:42)
09-14 11:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(25124):    at com.deliveryscience.pod.handlers.OrderDataRetrieval$1.onResponse(OrderDataRetrieval.java:1)
09-14 11:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(25124):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
09-14 11:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(25124):    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
09-14 11:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(25124):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
09-14 11:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(25124):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
09-14 11:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(25124):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
09-14 11:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(25124):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
09-14 11:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(25124):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 11:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(25124):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-14 11:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(25124):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
09-14 11:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(25124):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
09-14 11:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(25124):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `getActivity()` before that your Fragment attaches to your Container Activity.
you should initialize Activity Context on `onAttch()` or using getAcitivty() on onActivityCreated(). onCreateView() or onViewCreated() will call before Fragment attaches to Activity.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) 
{
    //Initializing Activity Context
}
```

Comment: I added **getActivity()** to on **onAttach**, but it's still same thing

Comment: getActivity() nreturns Activity parent Context which you have it as an activity argument in onAttach(Activity activity). just define a global Context , then initialize it like activityContext = activity.

Comment: I've edited my code. It's still crashing and saying same thing

Comment: dont use parent activity Context or getActivity() in onCreateView() or onViewCreated().please read documentation for Fragment lifecycle.